# Skipping parameters in NSIS

Tags: nsis

I am new to `NSIS`, and there's a few things I don't understand.
Here's an example:

If I want to create a shortcut(`.lnk`) for my program, then I'll do something like

`CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\MYPROGRAM.lnk" "$INSTDIR\MYPROGRAM.exe"`

But as said [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#createshortcut),
I can include much more info than just that. What if I don't want to set any shortcut, all I want is to set that last description parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two parameters are required, the rest are optional. If you don't want to set a optional parameter you can simply provide a empty string.

The parameters are documented as:

> link.lnk target.file [parameters [icon.file [icon_index_number [start_options [keyboard_shortcut [description]]]]]]

and if you want to set the icon but not the parameters you need to call it like this:

```
CreateShortcut "$SMPROGRAMS\MYPROGRAM.lnk" "$INSTDIR\MYPROGRAM.exe" "" "$INSTDIR\MyIcon.ico"
```

To set the description you need to call it like this:

```
CreateShortcut "$SMPROGRAMS\MYPROGRAM.lnk" "$INSTDIR\MYPROGRAM.exe" "" "" "" "" "" "My Description"
```

Comment: Do you always use `""` to skip a parameter? what about using `0`?

Comment: `""` is the only way to skip a parameter. Using `0` in places where numbers are required will work but it is not the same thing, it will set the value, not skip it. And `0` might not even be the default if skipped (but it is for the icon index).